# Viewing mm files

Tags: man, groff

The ksh source code at 
https://github.com/att/ast/tree/master/src/cmd/ksh93
contains files ending with the `.mm` suffix.

E.g., https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/ksh93/PROMO.mm

At first glance, they look like man files but `man` doesn't view them well.
How can I view these files in some nicely readable form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an ASCII version

```
groff -Tascii -mm PROMO.mm
```

For a postcript version

```
groff -Tps -mm PROMO.mm
```